# "Get Latest" only on a folder, not recursively

Tags: version-control, tfs

Is there a way that I can "Get Latest" on a folder/branch by itself, without recursing through everything? Our source is a couple of GB, and I just want to basically have the latest version of the branch itself (or maybe just all of the folders), but not any of the contents.

If you're wondering why... it's because you can't delete a branch until you have downloaded it from TFS. If the branch is greyed out, you cannot delete it. So I want to be able to get latest on a folder/branch without it recursing inside.

Comment: There's no way I can think of to do this from within Visual Studio - you must pend a delete against the latest version of the file (in order to resolve conflicts when you pend a delete but someone checks in a newer version before you check-in your delete.)  Are you open to writing a tool against the API to do this?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You can't do it from within Visual Studio, but you can from the [command line](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fx7sdeyf.aspx).

Open up a "visual studio command prompt" from the start menu and navigate to your local workspace e.g. cd c:\tfs\myteamproject\mybranch

then use the command "tf get $/myteamproject/mybranch/theFolderIWantToDelete"

This will only get that specific folder, you can then go back to VS and delete the folder and check it in.

Comment: Did not do anything for me. Says 'All files are upto date". I did use tf get /force $path